# Custom Button like iOS Clear Button In Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I need to add clear button in table view section header. It is exactly same like the one in notification center. So when user clicks it, 'x' will change to 'Clear'. If s/he clicks it again, app will perform action. But any click outside this button, 'Clear' will be back to 'x'.

Reference: http://share.framerjs.com/5hc7e6kwtwfm/